# live update value if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to update a textbox based on whether or not a checkbox is checked or not. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891734/how-can-i-update-a-set-of-text-fields-on-key-press-and-avoid-resetting-a-form-on) I got a text box working fine, but I can't get a checkbox to update the value. What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sum totals</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function calculate(t){
        var j = document.getElementById("output");
        var rege = /^[0-9]*$/;
        if ( rege.test(t.tons.value) ) {
            var treesSaved = t.tons.value * 17;
            j.value = treesSaved;
        }
        else
            alert("Error in input");
        }

  $('input[name="selectedItems1"]').click(function(){
    var j = document.getElementById("output");
    if (this.checked) {
      j.value=j.value+300
    }else{
      j.value=j.value-300
    }
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tons" id="tons" onkeyup="calculate(this.form)"/>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />I have a car
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="output" value="Output" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put $('input[name="selectedItems1"]').click() in document.ready

Comment: you want to get the status of the `checkbox` if any change happen to the `textfield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `<script>` tag after `<form>`

**Reason**:

When the html page loads, it'll be interpreted line by line. When it come to `click()`, jQuery will try to find the element `input[name="selectedItems1"]` which won't be loaded into the DOM at that time. So, jQuery won't attach the `click()` event handle to that checkbox. That's the reason why your code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>sum totals</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function calculate(){
        var j = document.getElementById("output");
        var rege = /^[0-9]*$/;
        var tons = $('#tons').val();
        if ( rege.test(tons) ) {
            val = parseInt(tons);
            var treesSaved = val * 17;
            if($('input[name="selectedItems1"]').is(":checked"))
            {
                treesSaved = treesSaved +300;
            }
            else
            {
                treesSaved = treesSaved -300;
            }
            if(isNaN(treesSaved))
                j.value=0
            else
                j.value=treesSaved;
        }
        else
            alert("Error in input");
        }
$(function(){
  $('input[name="selectedItems1"]').change(function(){
    calculate();
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tons" id="tons" onkeyup="calculate()"/>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />I have a car
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="output" value="Output" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```